# How to use an apply function together wih a conditional?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply

The dataframe I'm using has a column named 'Sex' filled with 'male'/ 'female'.
I need to change 'male'/'female' for a number, namely 0 or 1.

I'm trying the following code

```
result =  df.apply(lambda x: 1 if x == 'male' else 0, )
```

and the error is

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'Sex'
```

Comment: Use `pd.Series.map` and pass a mapping dictionary like `{'male':0, 'female':1}`

Comment: Could you please provide a little bit more of the code you have? The lines you posted don't seem to be the ones causing the error.

Comment: the dataframe I'm coding on is kaggle's titanic ML challenge

Answer (score 0):

```py
label_dict = {'male':0, 'female':1}
df['Sex'] = df.category.replace(label_dict)
```

You could use a dictionary that maps the values in the dataframe column to their corresponding values in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Version using `.replace`

```py
df['Sex'] = df['Sex'].replace({'male': 1, 'female': 0})
```

Version using `.map`

```py
df['Sex'] = df['Sex'].map({'male': 1, 'female': 0})
```

Version using boolean casting

```py
df['Sex'] = (df['Sex'] == 'male').astype(int)
```

This last version has the advantage to make all values different than male as 0